# WPF XAML namespace refactoring

Tags: data-binding, xaml, refactoring

Consider a `ViewModel` and a `View` that uses it, where the `DataContext` is set to the VM in the code behind file.

When they are both at the project namespace, the view runs without exceptions with binding statements along the lines of:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PrefixFilterChoices}"
```

where `PrefixFilterChoices` is a property on the VM.

When I refactor the project so that `ViewModels` and `Views` are each in their own namespace within the project, I now get a runtime error:

> (System.IO.IOException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll, cannot find the resource projectView.xaml).

1) I can't figure out who is looking for the resource though, so I'm not sure what the fix is. The code behind is still setting the `DataContext` and it has the new namespace for the `ViewModel`. Must I add it to the XAML also? Must I alias it and now qualify the Path for all of the bindings?

2) I use resharper, which has always been spot on the money at refactoring namespace changes; but it isn't helping even a little with the XAML. Are there any tools that do better XAML refactorings?

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the answer is that refactoring the namespace affected the application StartupUri. I couldn't get the format right in the xaml so I just set the MainWindow in an application startup event.